# C# WinRT/Metro app - ScrollViewer paging

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I need to implement horizontal paging functionality on `ScrollViewer` like in iOS.
To do that I need to catch the event when `ScrollViewer` did ends decelerating, but `ScrollViewer` doesn't have that kind of events like in IOS, e.g.
`-scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:`
`-scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:` ,etc...

Does any one know how to catch those events, or suggest a better method how to achieve paging functionality, or may be you know a 3rd party already implemented ScrollViewer with paging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what paging means in iOS, but if I am guessing correctly - you might be interested in looking at `HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment` and `HorizontalSnapPointsType` properties. Or even better just use the `FlipView` control. The two properties will allow the `ScrollViewer` to automatically snap to elements of the `ItemsPanel(Root)`, so for example if the panel is an `(Items)StackPanel` - it will snap to the elements of that and thus give you the page snap behavior in a control similar to the `FlipView`.

Comment: Thank you very much Filip. FlipView is exactly what I'm looking for. 
Now I have another problem with WebViews and ScrollViews, may be You can help me here too? I'm stuck 2 days on this question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296790/winrt-multiple-webviews-inside-scrollviewer?noredirect=1#comment43058935_27296790